# Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() для sd card

Tags: android

С помощью этой функции я получаю список папок с музыкой на телефоне

```
public ArrayList<ModelFolder> scanFolders(File dir){
    String d;
    File[] files = dir.listFiles();
    for(File file:files){

        if(file.isDirectory()) {
            scanFolders(file); }
        else
        {
        if(file.getAbsolutePath().endsWith(".mp3")) {

            int i = dir.toString().lastIndexOf("/");
            d= dir.toString().substring(i+1);
            String count = CountInFolder(dir.toString());
            if(data.size()>0){
            if(data.get(data.size()-1).getTitle().equals(d)){
                }
                else {

                data.add(new ModelFolder(d,"",dir.toString(),count));

                }
            }
            else{
                data.add(new ModelFolder(d,"",dir.toString(),""));

            }
        }
        }
    }

    return data;

}
m.scanFolders(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory());
```

Но мне нужно сканировать и на sd карте. Как это реализовать?

Comment: А с помощью cursor и MediaStore не пробовали?

Comment: А можно пример?

Comment: Вот, например http://stackoverflow.com/a/33383909/4829111

Comment: Сделал как там. Все равно не видит sd card

Answer (score 1):

Начиная с Android 4.4 в SDK есть функция `Context.getExternalFilesDirs(String)`
, возвращает пути к накопителям. Работает, но не всегда. В своем проекте получаю пути к внешнему и внутреннему накопителю таким образом:

```
        ArrayList<String> allPaths = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> sdPaths = new ArrayList<>();
        for (File file : context.getExternalFilesDirs("external")) {
            if (file != null) {
                int index = file.getAbsolutePath().lastIndexOf("/Android/data");
                if (index > 0) {
                    String path = file.getAbsolutePath().substring(0, index);
                    try {
                        path = new File(path).getCanonicalPath();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.e("Exc getExtSdCardPaths", e.getCause().toString());
                    }
                    allPaths.add(path);
                    if (!file.equals(context.getExternalFilesDir("external"))) {
                        sdPaths.add(path);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: И что будет в allPaths и что в sdPaths?

Comment: Ну по названиям переменных: allpaths- все пути(карта и внутренняя память) и sdpaths - пути к карте